# Binary Tree Struct containing Multiple Arrays

Tags: c, binary-tree

Just as a disclaimer, I am not looking for any hard code solutions, but merely a nudge in the right direction.

Essentially, I need to create a tree, that contains two arrays of data in each Node and two separate arrays of chars.

```
struct Node {
    char *name;
    char *number;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *left;
};
```

That's my struct at the moment, and the input is in the form:

```
name number
name number
name number
.
```

The `.` being the termination, now, I have a theory for how to parse that, i.e. `getchar` until `.` and `scanf` the `name` and `number` into an array. But from this point, I'm unsure how exactly I need to pass those arrays to a function to add the stuff to the tree, where I define the size of the array, etc. Can someone give some tips for this problem?

Comment: `node->name = strdup(inputname);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use dynamic memory. The size of your arrays will be defined at runtime, after you have read them, from a file I guess.

If the `char*` you read are null-terminated (i.e. the last character is '\0'), you can use the `strlen` function to get their size, and pass that value to `malloc` in order to allocate the memory before you use `strcpy` to copy the string into that memory. Don't forget to call `free` to return everything you `malloc`'ed

So just pass two `char*` to the function which will insert them in your data structure (is it a binary tree or a try? You used one term in the title and another in your question)

Answer (score 0):

searched google for "c binary tree tutorial":
 http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson18.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do a stack type:

```
typedef struct
{
int pos;
char *array;
int size;
} charArray;

charArray *newCharArray();

void pushCharArray(charArray * ca, char c);
void popCharArray(charArray *ca);


charStack *name;
charStack *number;
```

Inside pushCharArray you should check if ca is null or not, increment size if you need more space, increment the position...